# App crashes on performSegue in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

This problem never occurred before and worked on previous apps before I updated to the mac osx 10.10 beta. Now, if I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];` in the viewDidAppear method I receive this error message,

> ```
> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
> (SecondViewController: 0x15d9ddc0) has no segue with identifier
> 'segueName''"
> ```

The segue exists and works fine as long as it's not in the viewDidAppear method. The only exception to this is if the destination view controller isn't attached to a class in the storyboard.

Comment: I didn't know the segue feature is also available for Mac OS X.

Comment: I don't know either I'm working with iOS :P

Comment: You sure the controller has loaded via the storyboard? If it hasn't there may not be a segue to load. Also, double check you haven't got the ID strings wrong, there's always a chance you've missed something. Lastly, if you're acquiring the ID String from somewhere else, output it to the console just to make sure it's being sent through correctly. EDIT: Didn't read the last bit where you say it's in the storyboard, so without seeing more I'm at a loss. Sorry.

Comment: The segue works perfectly fine as well if the second view controller isn't linked to a view controller class

Comment: You sending any parameters through in the prepareForSegue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel kinda stupid now I was subclassing the view controllers under the default ViewController class automatically generated by apple instead of the UIViewController class.